# Get unicode symbol instead of emoji

Tags: android, text, unicode, emoji, spannablestring

In my app I need `EditText` with `SpannableString`. When I receive a special character, like `✝` for exemple, the char is converted to the corresponding emoji.
This "issue" isn't on all devices, for exemple it happens on Samsung, but not on a AOSP Android

How can I "force" to get the special char and not the emoji ?

**A SOLUTION :**

I've found this solution to get the right result, but I don't know if it's a good thing or not :

```kotlin
val specialChar = "✝︎"
val symbole = StringBuilder(specialChar).append(0xFE0E.toChar()).toString()
```

With that code, I get the special char instead of emoji

Comment: The problem is in font and in the font settings (fonts, with fonts settings/flags, decides the substitutions)

Comment: Your solution is reasonable. When emoji were first added to Unicode, if there was already a symbol in Unicode that was a black and white equivalent to the emoji, then the given emoji was unified with that symbol. Later it was recognized that wasn't the best choice because it led to issues like what you encountered. To control whether text (symbol) or emoji presentation is intended, variation sequences were defined to specify the desired appearance. Appending U+FE0E is using one of these sequences. See https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Variation_Sequences.